# Condition for set to be closed.

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Consider the convex set with the following property: $A \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, and $A \cap [a,b]$ is closed for all segments. Then $A$ is also closed.

My idea is fully geometrical. Suppose we have some limit point $a$ that doesn't belong to $A$. Then $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \cap A \ne \emptyset$. So there are at least two points $a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon \in A$ (otherwise $a$ isn't limit point). So we have $[a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon] \cap A = [a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon]$ (because of convexity if $a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon \in A$, then $\alpha a_\varepsilon + (1 - \alpha) b_\varepsilon \in A$). Let $\varepsilon \to 0$, we have a sequence of decreasing segments $[a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon] \to \{a\}$.  Since all intersection with segments are closed, then in limit $a$ will be in $A$.

*N.B.* to be added: these $[a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon]$ shouldn't be nested. That's the crucial point in this proof. Also from geometrical point of view if $a$ not in $A$, there should be a segment $[a, c]$ :  $[a,c] \cap A = [a, c]$ and hence $a \in A$, but I'm not certain how to prove this staitment.

Here I'm not sure about the last proposition: *a will be in A*. How can I show it more precisely?

Comment: You can be more precise by writing clearly, for starters. You haven't related $a_n,b_n$ to $a$ at all, so as $\epsilon\gt0$ nothing happens whatsoever, from my perspective

Comment: @FShrike we can set $\varepsilon = 2^{-n}$ and it will be enough. But okay, I've changed the notation.

Comment: No, no. You still haven't related $a_n,b_n$ to $a$. You have just told me they are elements of $A$.!

Comment: @FShrike maybe I miss something. For each $n$ we have: $a_n, b_n \in B_{2^{-n}}(a) \cap A$. Since there are two points, then there is a segment $[a_n, b_n] = A \cap[a_n, b_n]$ (by convexity).

Comment: Now you've said what you need to say. You also need to prove that you can definitely find $a_n,b_n$ to be distinct points

Comment: And also you need $a$ to lie in this intervals $[a_\epsilon,b_\epsilon]$ otherwise those intervals will converge to nothing

Comment: @FShrike 1) if $a_n = b_n$, then if we will increase $n$ there will be a moment $N:$ $B_{2^{-N}}(a) \cap A = \emptyset$, hence $a$ isn't limit point. Otherwise $a_n = b_n = a$ (isn't possible, since $a$ is limit point). 
2) $a$ shouldn't be in $[a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon]$ that's the point. These segments shouldn't be nested. Assume our set is unit circle and $a_n = (\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+2}\right), \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+2}\right))$, $b_n = (\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+2}\right), -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+2}\right)$. Then $[a_n, b_n]$ in limit they will be the point (1, 0).

Comment: If $B$ is closed then $\overline B=B$. So if $a$ is a limit point of $A$ then let $B=A\cap [a-1,a+1].$ Then $a\in \overline B=B\subseteq A$, so $a\in A.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet what if $A \cap [a-1,a+1] = [c,d]$ where $a < c$? Or in this case, $a$ isn't limit?

Comment: If $a<c$ and $A\cap [a-1,a+1]=[c,d]$ then $(a-1,c)$ is a neighborhood (nbhd) of $a$ that's disjoint from $A$ so $a$ is not a limit point of $A$.... In general, if $a\in\overline A$ and if $U$ is a nbhd of $a$ (e.g. $U=[a-1,a+1])$ then $a \in\overline {A\cap U}. $ Otherwise $a$ would have a nbhd $V$ that's disjoint from $A\cap U.$ But then $U\cap V$ would be a nbhd of $a$ that's disjoint from $A$, contrary to $a\in \overline A.$... (A nbhd of a point $a$ in a space $X$ is any $U\subseteq X$ such that there is an open set $O$ with $a\in O\subseteq U.$)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you can potentially approach $a$ by a path that is not an interval. $(a-1,c)$ is not an open set in dimension greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any easy way towards the conclusion from your arguments, you did not yet use the assumed property explicitly.

I propose a solution by "induction" with respect to the dimension. I will explain it for $d=2,3$, higher should also work this way, but the apparent large number of exceptional cases makes it much more tedious.

First $d=2$: we may assume that $a = (0,0)$ and there exists $a_1 = (1,0)\in A$. Then, since $a$ is a limit point, there exist $a_n = (x_n,y_n)\in A$ such that $|a_n|\leq \frac 1n$. We may assume in addition that $x_n\geq 0$, because the interval $[a_1,a_n]$ belongs to $A$, hence if there was a point on it whose $x$ coordinate vanishes, then it would be closer to 0 than $a_n$.

If there is an infinite number of $a_n$'s both over and under the $x$-axis, it is easy to see that the interval $(a,a_1]$ belongs to $A$, and so $a\in A$ by our assumption. Assume then that almost all $a_n$'s lie strictly above the $x$-axis. Consider triangles $\Delta a_1 a_2 a_n$ for $n\geq 3$ (almost all of them are non-degenerate). Their union is a subset of $A$ and it is easy to see that for every $x\in (0,1)$ it contains a line segment of the form $\{x\}\times (0,\epsilon(x))$. Thus, our assumption implies that $A$ contains every point $(x,0)$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and the assertion follows. This ends the case $d=2$.

For $d=3$ we start with similar simplifications: $a=0$, $a_1 = (1,0,0)$, and $a_n$'s have non-negative $x$ coordinate (i.e. $x_n\geq 0$). Assume (WLOG) that $y_2=0$, $z_2>0$ and let $\pi= OXY$ – the vertical plane. If there is an infinite number of $a_n$'s below $OXY$, then the situation reduces to $d=2$, because $a$ is then a limit point of the two-dimensional convex set $A\cap \pi$. We can also reduce to $2d$ if an infinite number of $a_n$'s belong to $OXZ$ or lie on both sides of $OXZ$. We have therefore reduced situation to $x_n,y_n,z_n> 0$ for $n\geq 3$. Consider the tetrahedra $\Delta a_1a_2a_3a_n$ for $n\geq 4$. Their union is a subset of $A$ and for all $(x,0,z)$ belonging to the triangle $\Delta aa_1a_2$ there exists an interval $[(x,0,z),(x,\epsilon(x,z),z)]$ belonging to $A$. Thus our assumption implies that $\Delta aa_1a_2\subseteq A$ and so $a\in A$.

Comment: What is $a_2$ in $d=2$ case?

Comment: It's an arbitrary point in $A$ which lies at the distance less than or equal $1/2$ from $a$.

Comment: The crucial problem here is: $(x, 0)$ in $A$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. Why then $(0,0)$ in $A$. If we suppose that from $x_n \to x$ and $(x_n, 0) \in A$ we have $(0,0) \in A$, then I guess we assume that $A$ is closed (since it contains its limit point).

Comment: If $(0,0)$ does not belong to $A$, then $A\cap [(0,0),(1,0)]= ((0,0),(1,0)]$ is not closed which contradicts the assumption of $A\cap [a,b]$ being closed.